# Can't get Bitamp from ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to get a Bitmap from a video which I get from the device's gallery or the camera, but when I call this, I'm getting a null Bitmap:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Uri uri = data.getData();
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Uri videoUri = data.getData(); // -> content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/video%3A76

        // This returns null
        Bitmap thumbnailVideo = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(videoUri.toString(), MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);

        media1.setImageBitmap(thumbnailVideo);
    }
```

I also tried using this, but it stills returns a null value:

```
String path = uri.getPath(); // -> /document/video:76
Bitmap thumbnailVideo = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(path , MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
```

And the last thing I tried is this code, but as before, it doesn't work:

```
String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA};
Cursor cursor = this.getContentResolver().query(uri, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
cursor.moveToFirst();
int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
cursor.close();

Bitmap thumbnailVideo = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(picturePath, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
```

What am I doing wrong? I tried different solutions from Stackoverflow but none of them seem to work for me.

Comment: `String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);` You forgot to tell the value you obtained for picturePath.

Comment: @greenapps I'm getting this: 

W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message

Comment: Is that an answer for my question?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I get when I try to Log.d the value of picturePath.

Comment: Can be. But with that you did not tell the value.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get what you're trying to say.

Comment: I wanted you to tell us that the value of picturePath was null. That picturePath was null.

Comment: Well, yes, if I got a NullPointerException it's obviously because the value is null. But why is it null?

Comment: Its null because the mediastore is not in for telling you a path. It gave you an uri. Use it.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to make this work.

```
try {
    Bitmap thumbnailVideo;

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
        thumbnailVideo = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(getRealPathFromURIForVideoAPI18(videoUri), MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
    }
    else {
        thumbnailVideo = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(getRealPathFromURIForVideoAPI19(videoUri), MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
    }
    setThumbnail(thumbnailVideo);
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
// API 18 or less (Android 4.3)
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public String getRealPathFromURIForVideoAPI18(Uri contentUri) {
    String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
    String result = null;

    CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(this, contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
    Cursor cursor = cursorLoader.loadInBackground();

    if (cursor != null) {
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        result = cursor.getString(column_index);
        cursor.close();
    }
    return result;
}

// API 19 or higher (>Android 4.4 Kitkat)
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
private String getRealPathFromURIForVideoAPI19(Uri selectedVideoUri) {
    String wholeID = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(selectedVideoUri);
    String id = wholeID.split(":")[1];

    String[] column = { MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA };
    String sel = MediaStore.Video.Media._ID + "=?";
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, column, sel, new String[]{ id }, null);
    String filePath = "";

    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(column[0]);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
    }
    cursor.close();
    return filePath;
}
```